# Error occurs Database Attaching to SQL server Management 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

Can i upgrade my sql 2012 706 version to 852 version because this DB support 852 version? I also tried run as administration picture is attached.

SQL DB Attaching Error:

[[image: 1]]

Comment: The error means you are trying to attach a SQL Server 2016 database to a SQL Server 2012 instance. It is not possible to downgrade a database with attach or restore. The older database version has no knowledge of the future version to do that.

Comment: Alright so i have to upgrade my sql  to 2016 or pluss?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to upgrade or have another instance of SQL 2016+ to attach the database.